# How do you tell Emacs to leave the case alone in a search and replace string?

Tags: emacs, replace, case-sensitive

I'm trying to perform a regex search and replace in Emacs (using `M-x query-replace-regexp`), but the usually helpful smart case is getting in the way.  My source is:

```
One
Two
Three
```

And I want to replace each line with something like `<item name="One"/>` instead.  Unfortunately the capital at the start of each line is being misinterpreted, and I'm getting `<Item>` with an uppercase that I don't want.

I can find examples about how to make the search case sensitive, and how to keep the `\1` lowercase in the replacement string, but nothing about how to keep the entire replacement string case-unmodified.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this to your .emacs:

```
(setq case-replace nil)
```

<kbd>C-h v case-replace RET</kbd>:

> Documentation: Non-nil means `query-replace' should preserve case in
> replacements.

And a link to the manual for
[Replace Commands and Lax Matches](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replacement-and-Lax-Matches.html) details all the interactions with case and the appropriate variables.

Or you could define a new command like:

```
(defun query-replace-no-case ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((case-replace nil))
       (call-interactively 'query-replace))))
```

And, if you were coding this up in a function, and only wanted to set the variable temporarily, you'd do something like:

```
(let ((case-replace nil))
   (while (search-forward ...)
       (replace-match ...)))
```

Comment: For a one-off, hardly makes sense to put in your `.emacs`.

Comment: (`let ((case-replace nil))` can be written simply as `(let (case-replace)`

Answer (score -1):

In a current emacs, you can find the option in the **Options menu**. Save Options, if you wish through the same menu.